# Creative Cognito Forms notification email that contains all form details

Tags: cognito-forms, notifications, formatting

I would like the email that I receive as a notification from a Cognito Forms entry to have the same formatting as the PDF document I can download. I would want it to look like the form as it is being filled out. Currently when I include entry details into the notification emails, it just lists the entries without the form questions. I can see the Document Template upon submission, which is the same as the pdf file attached to the email, but I would like the body of the email to have that information as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include your own entry details in the body portion of the message by picking fields to include in the message body. This is an alternative to selecting to include all entry details, which uses a table to show each field and value.

We do hope to offer additional styling options for notification/confirmation emails in the future. Feel free to stop by our Idea Board and leave your feedback:

https://trello.com/c/BJfLEXJ2/251-additional-styling-options-for-notification-confirmation-emails